# ErrNo 2: No such file or directory - no solution found

Tags: python

I know this question has been answered many times before and I tried applying all of the solutions but still getting an error -

C:\Users\joshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\joshi\Desktop\Usersjoshi.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2021.3.680753044pythonFilespyvsc-run-isolated.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

also when I say pip show autopep8 - it gives me below message -
Version: 1.5.4
Summary: A tool that automatically formats Python code to conform to the PEP 8 style guide
Home-page: https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8
Author: Hideo Hattori
Author-email: hhatto.jp@gmail.com
License: Expat License
Location: c:\users\joshi\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages
Requires: pycodestyle, toml
Required-by:
(base

Comment: Please help yourselves by taking the [Intro Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Try reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also go through [Minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to post your code so that you can get answers in an efficient way.

Comment: Hello, is the `.py` file really on the desktop?

Comment: @T0ny1234 - yes working from my desktop

Comment: Also when I say pip show autopep8 - it does show me that -
Version: 1.5.4
Summary: A tool that automatically formats Python code to conform to the PEP 8 style guide
Home-page: https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8
Author: Hideo Hattori
Author-email: hhatto.jp@gmail.com
License: Expat License
Location: c:\users\joshi\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages
Requires: pycodestyle, toml
Required-by:
(base

Comment: @VaiJos Probably missunderstanding but I asked is the `Usersjoshi.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2021.3.680753044pythonFilespyvsc-run-isolated.py` placed on the desktop?

Comment: @T0ny1234 - No , its not on desktop. also I tried your solution below but getting same error. possible for us to connect onlne maybe - Liveshare? :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13945) you can try:

> 1. Uninstall Python extension (if you have pylance uninstall it first).
> 2. Close all instances of VS Code.
> 3. Go to, %USERPROFILE%/.vscode/extensions (on windows) or ~/.vscode/extensions on Linux/Mac.
> 4. Delete any folder with the name starting with ms-python.python*
> 5. Start VS Code, and install Python extension (also pylance if you uninstalled it in step 1).